# Weblogic connection pool ignores maximum capacity limits

Tags: java, oracle, hibernate, weblogic

In some cases, for unknown reason, I see that after some running time (~1day) WL ignores **Maximum Capacity** option.

And this is very strange, because **Pin-to-Thread** option is unchecked.

WL Restart or DataSorce recreation helps, but still ... maybe somebody faced same strange behavior and found an acceptable solution?

I have Oracle and Hibernate.

I am using *WebLogic Server Version: 12.1.3.0.0*

Here is my test app:

```
public class ConnectionTestServlet extends HttpServlet {
private static final Logger LOG = LoggerFactory.getLogger(ConnectionTestServlet.class);
private static int CNT = 0;

private static int successCnt = 0;
private static int failCnt = 0;

@Override
protected void doGet(final HttpServletRequest req, final HttpServletResponse resp) throws ServletException, IOException
{
    successCnt = 0;
    failCnt = 0;

    String dataSource = req.getParameter("ds");
    int threadCount = getValue(req, "count");
    int timeout = getValue(req, "time");
    LOG.info("CNT = [{}], TIME = [{}]", threadCount, timeout);

    for (int i = 0; i < threadCount; i++) {
        Thread worker = new Thread(() -> work(dataSource, resp, timeout));
        worker.start();
    }
}

private int getValue(HttpServletRequest req, String param) {
    String stringValue = req.getParameter(param);
    LOG.info("value = \"{}\"", stringValue);
    return stringValue == null || stringValue.equalsIgnoreCase("null") ? 0 : Integer.parseInt(stringValue);
}

private void work(String dataSourceName, HttpServletResponse resp, int timeout) {
    PrintWriter writer = null;
    Connection con = null;
    ++CNT;
    int id = CNT;
    try
    {
        LOG.info("Thread: {}", Thread.currentThread());
        writer = resp.getWriter();

        DataSource ds = getDataSource(new InitialContext(), dataSourceName);
        con = ds.getConnection();

        DatabaseMetaData metadata = con.getMetaData();
        LOG.info("url: {}", metadata.getURL());
        LOG.info("description: {}", con.toString());

        writer.append("current thread: " + Thread.currentThread());
        writer.append("\n");
        writer.append("url:").append(metadata.getURL());
        writer.append("\n");
        writer.append("description: ").append(con.toString());

        TimeUnit.SECONDS.sleep(timeout);
        successCnt++;
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        failCnt++;
        LOG.error("#{} :: {}", id, e.getMessage());
    }
    finally {
        --CNT;

        LOG.info("SUCCESS: {} &&& FAIL: {}", successCnt, failCnt);

        try {
            if (con != null) con.close();
            if (writer != null)
            {
                writer.flush();
                writer.close();
            }
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}

private DataSource getDataSource(InitialContext ctx, String name) {
    DataSource dataSource = null;
    try {
        dataSource = (DataSource) ctx.lookup(name);
        return dataSource;
    } catch (NamingException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return dataSource;
}
}
```

Comment: Can you share the wls version you are using and some values that show the max capacity is ignored. Thx

Comment: @EmmanuelCollin
I am using WebLogic Server Version: 12.1.3.0.0

In Connection Poll setting I set  
`max capacity` = 200;  
`Pin to Thread` = false;

After that I start my test app, and In monitoring tab see that I have as much open connections as I request.